# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio: assistant with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, adventureworks

I'm looking to write a stored procedure for a task named "Receive products and move it into inventory" with a related table name `ProductInventory` as shown below.

I want to write the SQL statement for this stored procedure using the `Update` command with parameters such as `[ProductID]`, `[UnitPrice]`,...

[image]

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there, and the SQL Server official documentation is very good also. Please make use of these resources and only post a question here when you have a specific technical issue.

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15 . Word of advice...get the plain SQL working the way you want, then convert to a procedure

Comment: another tip if you are struggling with the syntax is to open the Management Studio, find the table of interest, then right click "Script Table as", then "UPDATE to" then New query window. This will give you a shell update statement. take a look at this tutorial showing you to paramaterize a stored procedure. https://www.tutorialgateway.org/update-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/